# Rebol and /local Object

Tags: rebol

The new function below doesn't work if Obj is local. If I remove it from /local it works. So what to do to make it work with a local Obj thanks ? Sure not hard for you.

```
Person: make object! [

Person: func[FirstName LastName][
     Self/FirstName: FirstName
     Self/LastName: LastName
     Print Self/FirstName
     Print Self/LastName
]
FirstName: ""
LastName: ""

]



new: func[Class [Object!] Param-Block [block!] /local Obj][
    Constructor: to-word pick pick Class 1 2
    Obj: Make Class []
    params: copy ""
    foreach param Param-Block [
      if string? param [
        param: rejoin [{"} param {"}]
      ]
      append params param
      append params " "
    ]
    do rejoin [{do get in Obj Constructor} { } params]
    Obj
]
;FOR TEST
John: new Person["John" "Doe"]
```

Would give

```
>> probe John
make object! [
    Person: func [FirstName LastName][
        Self/FirstName: FirstName
        Self/LastName: LastName
        Print Self/FirstName
        Print Self/LastName
    ]
    FirstName: ""
    LastName: ""
]
>>
```

That is FirstName and LastName are "" instead of "John" "Doe"

Comment: It worked as expected when I tried it. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: You have set John the value returned by new which in the test case is params which is a string of the value {"John" "Doe" }.

Comment: Copied bad version so corrected to return Obj in new.

My problem is:

Comment: FirstName and LastName are "" instead of "John" "Doe" see question update. It works if Obj is not local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works ...

```
    rebol []

    Person: make object! [
        Person: func [ names] [
            Self/FirstName: names/1
            Self/LastName: names/2
        ]
        FirstName: copy ""
        LastName: copy ""
    ]

    new: func [class [object!] param-block [block!]
        /local obj constructor 
    ] [
        constructor: second first class
        obj: make class []
        do get in obj constructor copy param-block
        obj
    ]

    test: new person [ "John" "Doe" ]
    probe test

    make object! [
        Person: func [names][
            Self/FirstName: names/1
            Self/LastName: names/2
        ]
        FirstName: "John"
        LastName: "Doe"
    ]

    test2: new person [ "Dick" "Nixon" ]
    probe test2

    make object! [
        Person: func [names][
            Self/FirstName: names/1
            Self/LastName: names/2
        ]
        FirstName: "Dick"
        LastName: "Nixon"

]
```